# List of products on oracle fusion

Tags: oracle, oracle-fusion-middleware

Hello I am looking for a way to pull a list of products from Oracle Fusion in order to pull the audit data using this rest api endpoint:

> fscmRestApi/fndAuditRESTService/audittrail/getaudithistory

A few examples of what I have is :

> HCMEmployeeWellness
>
> HcmPayroll
>
> HcmTalent

Which get passed to that endpoint how can I get a list of all the products either from the API or the database table that I can look in.